# Margin left and right only shows on the left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a left and right margin on something that is also 100% width. It seems to put both the left and the right margin on the left size (totaling 200px on the left and not 100px either side. What is the reason for this?

It's demonstrated here:

http://jsbin.com/xomocitono/1

```
<div id="main">
  Test
</div>

#main {width: 100%; margin-left: 100px; margin-right: 100px; background: red;}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Remove width: 100%; and it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use calc for subtracting margin `calc(100% - 200px);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Support [IE9 +](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

```css
#main {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  Test
</div>
```

Or you can just simply remove `width`

```css
#main {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  Test
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just remove the width?

Comment: yes that is also right

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's Margin left and right only shows on the left because you have given width to div as **100%**.

Just remove that width you will get proper output, but you have to replace your CSS code with this code:

```
#main {
   margin-left: 100px;
   margin-right: 100px;
   background: red;
}
```

In this code, the 100% width is gone, and it might be the problem why it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

The div is already 100%. Put only the margins.
http://jsfiddle.net/0df0emjc/

```
<div id="main">
  Test
</div>
#main {
    margin:0 100px 0 100px;
    background: red;
}
```